# would it be reasonable for antfolk to integrate into human culture in the 21st century?

Tags: society, humans, culture, modern-age

for context, antfolk are an intelligent species native to an area of africa, and are technically a species of ant. their description is "abnormally large (4 to 6 inch long) winged ants with three fingered claw like structures on their two front limbs, significantly better eyesight, and the ability to reproduce human speech with the skill of a parrot mimicking sounds by vibrating their jaws at the correct frequencies. resistant to the majority of insecticides, and with average lifespans of 16 years, upper bound of 30"
what im asking is not if they could evolve, but if discovered, would it be at all reasonable for them to integrate into human society? they're at a technological level thats most comparable to egypt or rome, and are efficient enough at technological advancement that it only took them about 150 years of having intelligence to develop this, being instinctively curious and inquisitive. they live in about 12 supercolonies that are, in a way, like countries. the specific time they're discovered in is december, 2017. please tell me if more information is needed and of what type.

Comment: I think if they tried to "integrate" into many parts of the world, the US for example, they'd be greeted with cans of RAID. In some parts of the world, they'd probably just be eaten. Avec or sans chocolate, your choice.

Comment: If they're bigger, they must be less, right?

Comment: On the question itself, by integrating, do you mean act like humans do (like, you have ants going shopping with humans at the same mall and sing karaoke), or some sort of accepted cohabitation, like, they don't kill each other on sight and allow people going through their land and make some trades, but not much more because they don't understand each other well?

Comment: Finale note : The topic's is a little similar to the one of the [Empire of the Ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_of_the_Ants_(novel)) novel by Bernard Werber. Not sure you can find it in your langage, but hopefully it can help you ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Beyond the pragmatic practical difficulties, Cultural aspects come strongly into play.

Your ants are remarkably like us in many respects, being able to talk, build structures (equivalent to Rome), sized similarly and manipulate objects.

Beyond, however, the practicality of being able to communicate with us, and beyond the physical ability to relate to each other, are cultural factors that need to be considered. Humans are very social creatures, and like it or not culture forms a very strong part of our identity, whether it is sexual, nationalistic, societal or even simply art/architectural.

So the following would all also need to be compatible/complimentary too to enable 'integration':

- Governance - do your Ants have a Queen, and all others are simply drones following orders? Is there any individualism at all? Would you want one in your house, if you know this Ant is simply an extension of a mono-genetic pool?
- Art and Architecture - do your Ants like to live in homes? Do humans like to live in Hives? What spatial or functional relationships need to exist in order to be able to co-exist together?
- Society and Sex - do your Ants have the ability to work in groups, cooperate with others even if they disagree, or work individually to a common purpose? For that matter, can humans work with them? Can they have a beer together, share experiences, and talk about sex, gender or taboo subjects? Humans often find these important.
- Purpose - what purpose do your Ants have for integration? Is it because they genuinely have a desire to be with others, and value our culture and individualism? Is it for political, or less intimate reasons? For humans to accept them, they need to be convinced of their reasons for being accepted.

There are many obstacles to overcome, many shared experiences that need to happen.

Unfortunately, humans themselves have demonstrated sometimes that even just small cultural differences can lead to conflict, let alone physical differences - so you would need to at least ensure a very enlightened human culture is willing to tackle these issues (which I am not sure if in 2017 this was common), but humans can surprise even ourselves, so the possibility of integration cannot be discarded completely.

Answer (score 2):

No: Human culture is intended to moderate and guide the behavior of a specific species of primate.

Primate conceptions of privacy, family, sport, politics, the weather, gender roles, rule of law, and many other things that we take for granted might be quite different to a species with a quite different brain structure and physical capabilities.

As an example, humans and dolphins can relate to each other emotionally and can even communicate to an extent. Dolphins are social in a way that we (think that we) understand. Yet dolphins do not understand birthday parties nor "tuesday" nor money nor flags of nations.

Super-ants would seem even more foreign.